# How to make javascript run on all browser?

Tags: php, javascript

I update my question by being abit more descriptive.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myPopup2() {
        var iMyWidth;
        var iMyHeight;

        //half the screen width minus half the new window width (plus 5 pixel borders).
        iMyWidth = (window.screen.width/2) - (75 + 10);

        //half the screen height minus half the new window height (plus title and status bars).
        iMyHeight = (window.screen.height/2) - (100 + 50);

        window.open( "xyz.php" ,Store Record" ,"status=yes,height=300,width=350,resizable=yes,left=" + iMyWidth + ",top=" + iMyHeight + ",screenX=" + iMyWidth + ",screenY=" + iMyHeight + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no");
    }
</script>
```

is the javascript which does not work with IE8. when i try it with FF 3.6.16 on windows7 it behaves strangely. Sometimes it displays the code in the pop up window.

Thanks,

Comment: Use a framework like jQuery or Prototype.

Comment: You're going to have to be a lot more specific.  Post the code that isn't working in the other browsers.

Comment: You need to provide more info

Comment: You have to figure out which are the functions that are browser specific and find the equivalent functions in the other browsers. Or use a library that abstracts from these issues.

Comment: Besides 42, the answer is jQuery.

Comment: Please post your JavaScript...

Comment: Firefox 3.6.16?  aw come on man!

Comment: You can use an IDE like Aptana that has javascript intellisense and displays browser compatibility for ie, ff for each js function in the intellisense

Comment: [ALL browsers?](http://www.user-agents.org/)

Comment: @naveen, smells like update is missing. :)

Comment: @Richards: sure. he still has mozilla with him :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use cross-browser compatible javascript. You can achieve this through [feature detection](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/). A good measure to accomplish this would be using a framework or library that does most of the feature detecting and cross-browsing for you, for example [jQuery](http://jquery.com). There are others like MooTools, Dojo, YUI, but they are not as widely used as jQuery, which is what I'd recommend you, it's easy to use, easy to learn, *pretty* intuitive, and quite fast.

If your problem is with a particular piece of javascript you own, please update your question with that code so we can help you make it cross-browser compatible.